# check if /en/ or /es/ in document.location

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to get the language that the user is using based on the document.location

urls are of the type:

```
domain.com/en/blabla.html
domain.com/es/blabla.html
domain.com/it/blabla.html
```

so i was trying like this:

```
function getLan(){
   var idioma = document.location;
   var idiomaTmp = idioma.split("/");
   return = idiomaTmp[1];
}
```

but (i don't understand but) i get this error at firebug

```
idioma.split is not a function
[Detener en este error] var idiomaTmp = idioma.split("/");
```

any idea why? or maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.location` is an Object. Although is does have a custom toString method, so that `alert(document.location)` shows the actual url, it itself is not a String, and String methods don't work on it. What you want is to convert this Object to a String before using String methods:

```
document.location.toString().split(...) etc
```

As for a better solution, try regular expressions:

```
var m = document.location.toString().match(/\/([a-z][a-z])\//)
language = m ? m[1] : "default";
```

Comment: Important language can also be `en_US` or something like that so use this regex: `/\/([a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{2})?)\//`

Answer (score 2):

You want `location.href` not `document.location`

Answer (score 0):

You'r first error in the code is that you don't need a `=` after `return`.

The second error is that `document.location` will return a object with details about the url and not a string.

Actually you want this (will only return the path)

```
window.location.pathname // example: /en/
```

So you'r function will look like this:

```
function getLang() {
    return window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

use document.location.href.split('/') instead of document.location.href.split("/") then if you need to use substring( , )

Comment: document.location.split is not a function

Comment: location.href.toString().split('/')[1]

Comment: location.href is already a string so you don't need `.toString()`